# Why does this RSpec example behave such

Tags: ruby, rspec

Just trying out some RSpec expectations and wondering why this happens

```
describe "rspec" do
    class Team
        def players_on
        11
        end
    end

    it "does wierd things" do           
        hometeam1 = Team.new
        hometeam1.should have(11).players_on         
    end
end
```

RSpec shows an error

```
 Failure/Error: hometeam1.should have(11).players_on
       expected 11 players_on, got 8
```

If I substitute 11 with 8 in the expectation it passes

Is something wrong with my computer ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using the `have` matcher incorrectly. From [the docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/built-in-matchers/have-n-items-matcher):

> RSpec provides several matchers that make it easy to set expectations about the
>   size of a collection…These work on any collection-like object—the object just needs to respond to `#size` or `#length` (or both).

Which means that it calls `size`/`length` on the object, so your expectation is the same as:

```
hometeam1.players_on.size.should == 11
```

and `11.size` is `8` (so `8.should == 11`, which is of course false). You should use a regular matcher instead:

```
hometeam1.players_on.should == 11
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i should have done....

```
describe "rspec" do
    class Team

        def initialize
            @x = ["tom","dick","harry"]
        end

        def players_on_field
            @x      
        end
    end

    it "does wierd things" do           
        hometeam1 = Team.new
        hometeam1.should have(3).players_on_field        
    end
end
```